# How to implement push notifications on a webapp using firebase, vue.js and cordova?

Tags: javascript, firebase, cordova, vue.js, push-notification

I am currently working on a project in which we build a webapp that will be built for Android and iOS devices.
We use cordova for our building process and vue.js as our framework.
Our app needs push notifications and we want to use Google's Firebase service for that.
I am currently only working on a localhost.

I have created the project in firebase as an webapp and successfully set it up by conducting a smoketest.
    -> Import all the libraries and installed CLI firebase-tools aswell as firebase in my project.
    -> Set up the firebase config and called a debug function in main.js and recieved a firebase object.

I launch my project by using npm run serve. The project launches, however I found the following error in my Browser Console:

> The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
>
> FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:8080/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:8080/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html'). (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).

**What I have tried so far:**

I have further researched the problem and it appears that cordova needs some sort of plugin to be able to handle certain firebase features.

I found the following two plugins: 
    - https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase
    - https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex

I also placed the Contents of firebase-messaging-sw.js into the public folder without much success.

However it says in it is only compatible with Android and iOS.
I would like a solution where I can use push notifications on webapps that run in my browser however.
Also I have tried targeting the service worker with something like this:

```
navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('/my-sw.js')
    .then((registration) => {
        firebase.messaging().useServiceWorker(registration);
    });
}
```

(Source: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-add-push-notifications-to-a-web-app-with-firebase-528a702e13e1/)

However that didn't work aswell.

How can I archive that I can have push notifications on my webapp using vue.js and firebase?

My project tree looks something like this:

[image]

The files of interest are   ./src/services/firebaseAPI.js in which I implemented my firebase features
                            ./src/firebase-messaging-sw.js which is my service worker
                            ./src/main.js which calls the requestPermission() function in my firebaseAPI.js

**Contents of firebaseAPI.js**

```
var firebase = require("firebase");

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "KEY HERE",
    authDomain: "KEY HERE",
    databaseURL: "KEY HERE",
    projectId: "KEY HERE",
    storageBucket: "KEY HERE",
    messagingSenderId: "KEY HERE",
    appId: "KEY HERE",
    measurementId: "KEY HERE"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

module.exports = {
    requestPermission: function () {
        messaging.requestPermission()
        .then(function () {
            console.log("request permission: true");
            return messaging.getToken();
        })
        .then(function (token) {
            console.log(token);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("request permission: false " + err);
        })
    },
    onMessage: function () {
        messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
            console.log("onMessage" + payload);
        })
    },
    debug: function () {
        console(firebase);
    }
}
```

**Contents of firebase-messaging-sw.js**

```
firebase.importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js');
firebase.importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
  messagingSenderId: "KEY HERE"
})
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

**Contents of main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import 'bootstrap';
import './assets/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import routes from './router/Routes';
import i18n from './i18n';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({routes});
const fbs = require('./services/firebaseAPI');

fbs.requestPermission();

new Vue({
  router,
  i18n,
  components: { App },
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Any help is appreciated.